# Recoger objetos de un ArrayList y cargarlos en otro

Tags: java

Estoy intentando dar una solucion a un problema. Tengo un `ArrayList<Personas>` y quiero recoger todos los registros que tenga en el campo `numeroPersonas` y generar otro `ArrayList`. Primero he creado un `ArrayList<String>` para recoger los diferentes datos que existen en ese campo y saber cuantos datos tengo diferentes. El problema viene cuando tengo que copiar un objeto que existe en mi **ArrayList todos** para generar otro **ArrayList grupo1**,**grupo2**,etc . Como puedo recoger un objeto de un `ArrayList`  y guardarlo en otro `ArrayList`.Seria recorrer uno y si cumple unos requisitos guardarlo en otro.

(es una explicacion rapida del problema ya que es un ArrayList con 10000 registros que tendra alrededor de 100 numeros diferentes en ese campo y tengo que generar un objeto para luego llamar a un metodo para generar un pdf con el objeto.Con lo que seria recorrer mi `ArrayList_principal` ->generar mi `ArrayList<Personas>_grupo1` llamar al metodo pasandole como parametro mi arrayList y asi hasta que termine con los grupos que recogere en un array los codigos que tengo)

Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: Te recomiendo que los filtros lo apliques en la consulta sql, manipular grandes cantidades de objetos por código no siempre es eficiente. Podrías agregar las estructuras de las tablas y las consultas que tienes para que quede mas claro :P

Comment: Puedes colocar el código que tienes ya hecho, para ver en que podemos ayudarte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me gusta entender porque no funciona con while pero he conseguido hacerlo con while y foreach.

`while(code.hasNext()){

        String b = code.next();
        for(personas valor:people ){




             if(valor.getNumeroEmpresa().equals(b)){


                 copia.add(valor);
             }


        }

        System.out.println("he guardado esto ");
        for(int i = 0; i < copia.size() ; i++){

            System.out.println(copia.get(i).getNumeroEmpresa());//en este punto enviaria el pdf.

        }

        copia.clear();

    }`

Gracias por vuestro tiempo al final he conseguido , me quedo con las ganas de saber porque no funciona el while dentro de otro.

Un saludo a tod@s

Answer (score 1):

Teniendo tu Array todos ya cargado con los objetos deseados (para el ejemplo te puse un objeto Cliente, el cual tiene un método **getGrupo()**, que devuelve el grupo al gual pertenece)

```
ArrayList<Cliente> todos = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
        ArrayList<Cliente> grupo1 = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
        ArrayList<Cliente> grupo2 = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {//
            todos.add(new Cliente()); // en esta parte cargas todos los objetos de la forma que lo estas haciendo 
        }                             //    
        for (Cliente cliente : todos) {
            if(cliente.getGrupo() == 1) {
                grupo1.add(cliente);
            }
            else if(cliente.getGrupo() == 2) {
                grupo2.add(cliente);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Si puedes usar `Java 8` (a estas alturas espero que sí), lo mejor sería que usaras las funcionalidades de `streams`:

Dada una lista de objetos `MiObjeto`, y suponiendo que filtras con un método `MiObjeto.cumpleFiltro()`:

```
List<MiObjeto> lista;
```

Obtienes un `stream` sobre la lista que quieres filtrar:

```
lista.stream()
```

Filtras sobre el `stream` en base al criterio deseado (en este caso `cumpleFiltro()`), con el método `filter`:

```
lista.stream().filter(item->item.cumpleFiltro())
```

Recuperas los objetos que cumplen el filtro con el método `collect`, y en forma de `List`:

```
lista.stream().filter(item->item.cumpleFiltro()).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Asignas el valor a la lista 2:

```
 List<MiObjeto> listaFiltrada = 
     lista.stream().filter(item->item.cumpleFiltro()).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Estoy intentando realizarlo con Iterator pero sigo quedandome en el punto de guardar el dato de arrayList general en uno especifico.Como podria recoger el objeto de un Iterator especifico para guardarlo en otro arrayList. Si no funciona probare hacerlo de esta manera que me indicas.Gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Iterator code = codigo.iterator(); // he recogido mi lista de numEmpresas diferentes de mi ArraList principa
ArrayList copia = new ArrayList(); //genero un array para realizar la copia de todos los registros por un mismo codigo

hile(code.hasNext()){
         String b = code.next();

`while(it.hasNext()){

         a = it.next();//objeto el objeto de mi ArraList principal



         if(a.getNumeroEmpresa().equals(b)){
             System.out.println("estoy dentro");
             copia.add(a);
         }   

       }

    }`

He conseguido obtener el objeto principal y guardarlo en un arrayList de copia el problema es que solo me realiza el primero y se para.Es decir despues de pasar por el primer while y recorrer el segundo. Al volver al primer while no vuelve a recorrer otra vez el segundo while.No entiendo el porque no me realiza el segundo while.

Un saludo y gracias por vuestro tiempo